# OpenCL: sum in parallel of n integers

Tags: c, algorithm, parallel-processing, sum, opencl

I need to create an OpenCL kernel function which uses parallel algorithm to sum `n` integers from an array `numbers`.

I should use an algorithm similar to the following:

```
parallel_summation(A):
    # ASSUME n = |A| is a power of 2 for simplicity

    # level 0:
    in parallel do:
      s[i] = A[i]                 for i = 0, 1, 2, ..., n-1

    # level 1:
    in parallel do:
      s[i] = s[i] + s[i+1]        for i = 0, 2, 4, ...

    # level 2:
    in parallel do:
      s[i] = s[i] + s[i+2]        for i = 0, 4, 8, ...

    # level 3:
    in parallel do:
      s[i] = s[i] + s[i+4]        for i = 0, 8, 16, ...

    # ...
    # level log_2( n ):
    s[0] = s[0] + s[n/2]

    return s[0]
```

So, I came up with the following kernel code:

```
kernel void summation(global uint* numbers,
                      global uint* sum,
                      const  uint  n,
                      const  uint  work_group_size,
                      local  uint* work_group_buf,
                      const  uint  num_of_levels) {

    // lets assume for now that the workgroup's size is 16,
    // which is a power of 2.


    int i = get_global_id(0);

    if(i >= n)
        return;

    int local_i = get_local_id(0);

    uint step = 1;
    uint offset = 0;

    for(uint k = 0; k < num_of_levels; ++k) {

        if(k == 0) {

            work_group_buf[local_i] = numbers[i];

        }  else {

            if(local_i % step == 0) {
                work_group_buf[local_i] += work_group_buf[local_i + offset];
            }

        }

        if(offset == 0) {
            offset = 1;
        } else {
            offset *= 2;
        }

        step *= 2;

        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    }

     atomic_add(sum, work_group_buf[0]);

}
```

But there's a bug because I'm not receiving the expected results. `numbers` is a buffer that contains numbers from `1` to `n`. `num_of_levels` is log<sub>2</sub>(number of work items per work group), which in my current example is 4 (log<sub>2</sub>(16)).

What am I doing wrong?

*Note: I'm not receiving any error, is just the result which is wrong. For example, I've an array of 1000000 elements from 0 to 999999, and the sum of those elements should be 1783293664, but I'm getting 1349447424.*

Comment: What did you learn via debugging this?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Nothing basically, I don't know how to debug the kernel code...

Comment: Why do you test if k is zero on every single iteration through your loop? It will only be zero the first time, so pull that outside the loop.

Comment: @MarkSetchell That's correct, thanks! Now I should do one less iteration theoretically... anyway, it doesn't seem to be solve the problem, but of course we knew this already :)

Comment: There's definitely a bug because in all work items at the end of the kernel I'm summing to `sum` the first element of `work_group_buf`, but I think I should just sum when `local_i == 0`...

Answer (score 2):

I fixed a few bugs. There were a few mistakes and I was missing this part `s[0] = s[0] + s[n/2]`, as you can see from this new version.

```
kernel void summation(global uint* numbers,
                          global uint* sum,
                          const  uint  n,
                          local  uint* work_group_buf,
                          const  uint  num_of_levels) {

        const int i = get_global_id(0);
        const int local_i = get_local_id(0);

        private uint step = 2;
        private uint offset = 1;


        if(i < n)
            work_group_buf[local_i] = numbers[i];

        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        for(uint k = 1; k < num_of_levels; ++k) {

            if((local_i % step) == 0) {
                work_group_buf[local_i] += work_group_buf[local_i + offset];
            }

            offset *= 2;
            step *= 2;

            barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
        }

        work_group_buf[0] += work_group_buf[get_local_size(0) / 2];

        if(local_i == 0)
            atomic_add(sum, work_group_buf[0]);

}
```

Note that now I'm adding to the final `sum` just the first element of each `work_group_buf` (i.e. `work_group_buf[0]`) only if the `local_i == 0`, because that position will contain the sum of all elements in the workgroup.

This actually seems to work for workgroups of size up to 32 (which are a power of 2). In other words, this kernel seems to work only for workgroups of size 2, 4, 8, 16 and 32 work items.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it simpler. It is very fast but work on OpenCL 1.2+ only.

```
inline void sum(__global int* a, int v)
{
    int s = +1 * v;
    int n = 0;
    int o = 0;
    do {
        n = s + atom_xchg(a, o);
        s = o + atom_xchg(a, n);
    }
    while (s != o);
}

__kernel void sum_kernel(__global int *set, __global int* out)
{
    int i = (get_group_id(0) + get_group_id(1)*get_num_groups(0)) * get_local_size(0) + get_local_id(0);

    sum(out, set[i]);
}
```

From: [GitHub - Hello GPU Compute World!](https://github.com/sowson/gpucomp)

Thanks!

Comment: Of course i parameter could be: a = i % 2; b = i % 4; etc. to make partitions, but I think you have the idea. The last worth to mention is that out is 1 element cl_mem buffer.